# find and add in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have two sets of results

[image]

I want to compare the two and add the values in **B** that is in **A** ( hope that make sense )

But I want to compare on 3 criteria ( Fruit, Color and Element )

So the 2 yellow lines will need to be appended to Table B.

The solutions Im thinking of is a repeating for loop in a for loop, but this might be a problem when you reach thousands of records to compare.

Is there perhaps a simpler way. The thing that stumps me is the fact that Table B has a extra column.

**example**

```
For (x , records in table (A), x++)
    $found = false;
    For(i, records in table (B), i++)
        if(tableA[x]['Fruit'] === tableB[i]['Fruit'])
            if(tableA[x]['Colour'] === tableB[i]['Colour'])
                if(tableA[x]['Element'] === tableB[i]['Element'])
                    $found = true;
                End if
            End if
        End if
    End for
    if(!$found)
        $f = tableA[x]['fruit'];
        $c = tableA[x]['Colour'];
        $e = tableA[x]['Element'];
        tableB[]['Fruit'] = $f;
        tableB[]['Colour'] = $c;
        tableB[]['Element'] = $e; 
        tableB[]['Object'] = "";
    End if
End for
```

Comment: Show Your *Tried* Code, First.

Comment: Okay, hang on I will post something in a few minutes. I was still planning, but will put some pseudo down.

Comment: Maybe this function will help You: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff-assoc.php ?

Comment: can you show how are you storing array in PHP instead of table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a little function that does the job. but its possibly the long way around. It does work though.

```
    private function filterResult ($resultArray, $checkArray) {

        // Loop trough the array with the eaxtra values 
        foreach($checkArray as $key => $value) {
            $fruit = $value['FRUIT'];
            $colr= $value['COLOUR'];
            $elem = $value['ELEMENT'];
            $cnt = 0;

            //Loop through array with final result to check if checkvalue exists
            foreach($resultArrayas $keyRA => $valueRA){
                $fruitChk = ($valueCI['FRUIT'] == $fruit ) ? true : false ;
                $colrChk = ($valueCI['COLOUR'] == $colr) ? true : false ;
                $elemChk = ($valueCI['ELEMENT'] == $elem ) ? true : false ;

                //Check on all 3 criteria and if value exist, increment counter
                if($fruitChk && $colrChk && $elemChk){
                    $cnt += 1;
                }
            }

            //If counter is = to zero. append checkArray element to ResultArray
            if($cnt == 0){
                $newdata =  array (
                    'FRUIT' => $value['FRUIT'],
                    'COLOUR' => $value['COLOUR'],
                    'ELEMENT' => $value['ELEMENT'],
                    'OBJECT' => "",
                );
                $resultArray[] = $newdata;
            }
        }

        //return result array
        return $resultArray;
    }
```